# Retain indent formatting when compiling a stored procedure without Data Studio

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, command-line, deployment

When I compile a stored procedure using CLPplus console (or even in dBeaver), all indentation is stripped out.  Only when I compile in Data Studio is the formatting retained, but I would like to deploy projects with a script.

I expect there is something simple I am missing, but have not been able to find a solution or even any other posts with the same issue.

Using CLPplus I ran this script file `@c:\temp\proc1.spsql`

```
create or replace procedure proc1()
begin
    declare vId int default 0;
    call dbms_output.put_line(vId+1);

/*
    Testing
*/
end
```

The `SELECT TEXT FROM SYSCAT.PROCEDURES WHERE PROCNAME = 'PROC1';` produced the the following:

```
create or replace procedure proc1()
begin
declare vId int default 0;
call dbms_output.put_line(vId+1);

/*
Testing
*/
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `SHOW` command to check to make sure CLPPlus has the `preservewhitespace` option and make sure it is ON.

If the option is not there you may have on old **clpplus.jar** file.

My problem was that the clpplus.jar file had date stamp 2011-‎04-‎01 ‏‎6:54 AM even though it shows **CLPPlus: Version 1.6** when it launches.

Answer (score 2):

It works fine for me in clpplus 1.6

```
$ clpplus -h | head -1
CLPPlus: Version 1.6
$ cat sql
create or replace procedure proc1()
begin
    declare vId int default 0;
    call dbms_output.put_line(vId+1);

/*
    Testing
*/
end
/
SELECT TEXT FROM SYSCAT.PROCEDURES WHERE PROCNAME = 'PROC1'
/
$ clpplus -nw $user/"$password"@$host:$port/$database @"$PWD"/sql
CLPPlus: Version 1.6
Copyright (c) 2009, 2011, IBM CORPORATION.  All rights reserved.


Database Connection Information :
---------------------------------
Hostname = localhost 
Database server = DB2/LINUXX8664  SQL11054 
SQL authorization ID = paul 
Local database alias = BP 
Port = 50003 


DB250000I: The command completed successfully.

create or replace procedure proc1()
begin
    declare vId int default 0;
    call dbms_output.put_line(vId+1);
/*
    Testing
*/
end                                                                                
SQL>
```

Comment: Well, curiously it has stripped out the blank line before the comment

Comment: Well, that is interesting.  I wonder if there is some type of configuration for CLPplus, since it is the same version as mine.

Comment: Are you using tabs or spaces as the prefix? I used spaces.

Comment: Good call, I switched to spaces...  Still stripped out :(

Comment: Humm. Not sure what else might be different about our environments. I’m using Linux but client OS should not matter. Raise with IBM support if you can

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware that either the CLP or Dbeaver strip formatting from Stored Procs (views in the CLP are a different matter unfortunately ).

For example, this is from Dbeaver

```
CREATE PROCEDURE P()
BEGIN
    RETURN 1;
END
```

then

```
SELECT TEXT FROM SYSCAT.PROCEDURES WHERE PROCNAME = 'P'
```

returns

```
CREATE PROCEDURE P()
BEGIN
    RETURN 1;
END
```

and from the command line, running Db2 11.5.4 , I can't reproduce your issue

```
$ db2 -td@ -vf test.sql 
create or replace procedure proc1()
begin
    declare vId int default 0;
    call dbms_output.put_line(vId+1);

/*
    Testing
*/
end

DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

$ db2 -x "SELECT TEXT FROM SYSCAT.PROCEDURES WHERE PROCNAME = 'PROC1'" | head --bytes 200
create or replace procedure proc1()
begin
    declare vId int default 0;
    call dbms_output.put_line(vId+1);

/*
    Testing
*/
end
```

If you don’t like what the CLP does to view DDL, but still want to create them from a command line tool, then you could use [CLPPlus](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.clpplus.doc/doc/r0054268.html) as that does not strip formatting I believe.

Comment: Point taken about Dbeaver.  Correct, it does retain the formatting as you pointed out.  I used Dbeaver view procedure option which messed up the formatting, so it is best to fetch the procedure back using SQL

Comment: I updated my question to focus on script with CLP.  I would still like to deploy using a script. Also, would like to retrieve the procedure using a script for that matter.

Comment: The Dbeaver view procedure might be an issue in an old version. If not raise it with the Dbeaver developers.

Comment: I compiled/deployed the test script using CLPplus now (and edited my question accordingly).  Still same result.  I am a developer, not a dba, and starting to wonder if there is something else at play.  At this point I am open to any ideas on alternative free options to deploy a procedure without Data Studio, for from a script using Data Studio if that were possible?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue myself using the db2 clp. What DB2 version are you using? Are you sure it is not something else that is stripping the leading spaces?

Comment: DB2 version 11.1.0.0 and clpplus version 1.4 (I noticed in clpplus it shows Database Server = DB2/LINUX8664 SQL11010 if that helps)

Comment: my above test with the clp (not clpplus) was from Db2 11.5.4.  However I sort of doubt that the clp behavior has changed.  Still 11.1.0.0 is getting quite old (should at least be on the latest 11.1 fixpack)

Comment: I need it to work work with CLPplus.

Comment: I've just tired in CLPPlus: Version 1.6,  and it does not strip leading spaces. If you can't update your sever level at this time, try with a newer client level.

Comment: You could ask IBM Support if this is a known issue in your older version of CLPPlus